# Bluetooth Keyboard only printing numbers. Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I have a new bluetooth keyboard, the [Anidees Prismatic 104](http://anidees.com/product/prismatic-rgb-keyboard-104/). I have succesfully connected it to my Ubuntu 19.04 Laptop but it is only printing numbers while connected via bluetooth, when conncted using a usb cable it works fine.

I understand that there is a similar problem with Apple Keyboards and turning off numpad usually works fine. My keyboard has a dedicated numpad and turning it off works but it means not being able to use the numpad. Is there a solution to use this keyboard with the dedicated numpad?

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me as well. I managed to fix it with:

```
numlockx off
```

If it works for you you can just add it to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: I have the sam problem as OP, but this didn't help me. 
Adding it for the record.

Comment: for anyone looking to solve problems with the Keychron K4, this helped me reset the numlock when other options like Fn+F6 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this issue, but I know my wireless keyboard has some crazy things I can enable and disable.  http://anidees.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/84K104K-User-Manual.pdf This is a link to that online manual.  It seems to have different selections for different operating systems (Windows, Windows10+, Mac, Android).  Maybe try the different selections to find if one works for you.  If not, it might not be compatible with Ubuntu.  Hope this will help in some way.